# asp.net gridview control cell reference value not working when the column is set to not visible

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview1 control and I want use the values in some columns, but I also want to hide these columns because the users do not need to see them and they also take up too much space in the display. However, when I hide the column and I try to use the value from the column I get the error "Input string was not in a correct format".

```
  //Here is the example of one column which I defined not visible:

   <asp:GridView ID="GridView9" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource9" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView9_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="WORKORDER_BASE_ID" HeaderText="WORKORDER_BASE_ID" SortExpression="WORKORDER_BASE_ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="WORKORDER_LOT_ID" HeaderText="WORKORDER_LOT_ID" SortExpression="WORKORDER_LOT_ID" Visible="False" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="WORKORDER_SPLIT_ID" HeaderText="WORKORDER_SPLIT_ID" SortExpression="WORKORDER_SPLIT_ID" Visible="False" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="WORKORDER_SUB_ID" HeaderText="WORKORDER_SUB_ID" SortExpression="WORKORDER_SUB_ID" Visible="False" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="SEQUENCE_NO" HeaderText="SEQUENCE_NO" SortExpression="SEQUENCE_NO" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="RESOURCE_ID" HeaderText="RESOURCE_ID" SortExpression="RESOURCE_ID" Visible="False" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="STATUS" HeaderText="STATUS" SortExpression="STATUS" Visible="False" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="RUN_COST_PER_HR" HeaderText="RUN_COST_PER_HR" SortExpression="RUN_COST_PER_HR" Visible="False"/>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource9" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:xyzConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [WORKORDER_BASE_ID], [WORKORDER_LOT_ID], [WORKORDER_SPLIT_ID], [WORKORDER_SUB_ID], [SEQUENCE_NO], [RESOURCE_ID], [STATUS], [RUN_COST_PER_HR] FROM [OPERATION] WHERE (([STATUS] = @STATUS) AND ([RESOURCE_ID] = @RESOURCE_ID))">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="R" Name="STATUS" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="XYZIBRA" Name="RESOURCE_ID" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

// then later I do this:

vHOURLY_COST = Convert.ToDecimal(GridView9.SelectedRow.Cells[8].Text);
```

If I remove the Visible="False" then the code executes successfully.

I found that once I make the column visible = false and the values for the column that is not visible becomes NULL, therefore I get the error "Input string was not in a correct format".

The question is how do I retrieve the column value and make the column not visible?

Comment: when you set it to false and use the debugger / QuickWatch what is the value of `GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[9]` also change to `GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[8]` to see if it has a value you need to reference the correct column position also make sure that the Auto Generate Columns property is set to false for the GridView are using ItemTemplate at all in your aspx code..?

Comment: I used the debugger and ran the code and I see the value for vHOURLY_COST as being 0 and as decimal type (don't know how to use the quickwatch - me newbie). This seem to indicate the value is correct.

Comment: there is a lot of documentation online in regards to how to use the debugger .. newbie or not.. you are not new to the internet as well as google so do a simple google search on how to use the debugger and all of it's features..

Comment: But now you got me thinking...I know before I started to hide some columns I know the array positions were correct, but if I hide some columns before GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[9] do I need to change the array number? i.e. if I hid two columns before  then do I have to refer the value as GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[7]?

Comment: @MethodMan - true.

Comment: that's correct.. since you are not showing the columns the index positions will be off by the total number of columns - the columns being hidden so count backwards keep in mind that column indexes are `0` based

Comment: Thanks that is good to know, but that will cause another issue for me. If I hide the column by Visible="False" which means I can't refer to it using the array position, then how would I retrieve the value from the hidden column for later use once I make that column not visible?

Comment: look up how to use an ItemTemplate

Answer (score 0):

Haven't got time to investigate properly, but from what I understand, if you have set Visible=False then the asp control will not be rendered at all to the page.  You're probably trying to convert an empty string to decimal.
Perhaps you could keep the original dataset in the Session variable or use CSS to hide the unwanted columns.

Comment: It is not the gridview control visible is set to false, rather it is the specific column that visible = false.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways of getting to values that you do not want displayed depending on where you need access to the values.

First things first.  If your datasource provides four fields [A,B,C,D] and your Gridview is bound to two fields [A,B] fields [C,D] are still available to use...depending on where you need them.

They are all available in the `RowDataBound` event:

**Datasource**

```
    --I'm assuming you have some data source that provides the equivalent of

    SELECT A,B,C,D from <your_table>
```

**Markup in .aspx**

```
    <%-- Fields A, B will be visible in GridView1. 
         Fields C, D will be NOT visible in GridView1 but are available in the code behind.              
      --%>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
      <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="A" HeaderText="Field A" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="B" HeaderText="Field B" />
      </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

**Code Behind**

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound( object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e )
    {
        if ( e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow )
        {
            // How to access the undisplayed fields
            DataRowView drv = (DataRowView) e.Row.DataItem;
            String FieldC = drv["C"];
            String FieldD = drv["D"];

            // How to persist data for access elsewhere in the code behind.
            // this will attach data to the <tr> tag in each data row
            e.Row.Attributes["field-c"] = FieldC
            e.Row.Attributes["field-d"] = FieldD
        }
    }
```

Alternatively, if you are not using the Editing features built into a gridview you can add the needed fields as data keys in the gridview:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
       DataKeyNames="C,D">
       . . .
    </asp:GridView>
```

Which will make the needed fields from a selected GridView row available via `GridView1.SelectedDataKey`:

```
    protected void btnSomeButton_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
      if( Gridview1.SelectedDataKey != null)
      {
         String FieldC = (String) GridView1.SelectedDataKey.Values[ "C" ];
         String FieldD = (String) GridView1.SelectedDataKey.Values[ "D" ];
      }
    }
```

Using the `DataKeyNames` property is not recommended if you plan on using the built in editing of a gridview as this property is intended for database primary keys. Adding extra data complicates automation of the Insert/Update/Delete commands.

Comment: I edited my question by adding the complete code above. I made my gridview control using the tools and also made the code behind procedure GridView9_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) by just double clicking the select text from the gridview control so I'm not sure how to do the GridView9_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) and make it tied to the gridview control. I think I understand the logic of your explanation, but I will need to research how to tie things together. thanks.

Comment: I'm getting namespace name could not be found for DataRowView. Is there a missing line in your code?

Comment: you may need to fully qualify it,i.e.: `System.Data.DataRowView` or add a using statement: `using System.Data` ro resolve the namespace error

Comment: Grabbing cell data by index values is a poor implementation especially when you have properly typed database sources available.  As you've found out cell index values are highly dependant on select statement field order and gridview field visibility.  Let me know specifically what you are trying to accomplish and I'll tailor this answer to your needs

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

[[ASP.NET: GridView value set to null when column is not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416861/asp-net-gridview-value-set-to-null-when-column-is-not-visible][1])

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Cells[1].Visible = false;
    e.Row.Cells[2].Visible = false;
}
```

But I just didn't know how to implement the GridView9_RowCreated event until now. I changed my very first line of the code to:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView9" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource9" OnRowCreated="GridView9_RowCreated" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView9_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

I tested it and it holds all column values and hides the columns.